# Vagrant laravel box, guest machine entered an invalid state

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Laravels Homestead vagrant box worked fine until today. After an windows auto update the server fails to start and throws the following error message:

The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'aborted' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

When i look in the log file of the machine i see the following error:

```
    d64.f9c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\crypt32.dll *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=00000000006fdf80:C:\Windows\system32
    d64.f9c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status -22900 (0xffffa68c)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll
    d64.f9c: Error (rc=0):
    d64.f9c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cached rc=Unknown Status -22900 (0xffffa68c) fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cErrorHits=2 \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll
    d64.f9c: Error (rc=0):
    d64.f9c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\Windows\system32\crypt32.dll': rcNt=0xc0000190
    d64.f9c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0xc0000190      'C:\Windows\system32\crypt32.dll'
    d64.f9c: Fatal error:
    d64.f9c: Error loading 'crypt32.dll': 1790 [C:\Windows\system32\crypt32.dll]
    fec.24d8: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(2): Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 rcNt=0x0
    1278.950: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(1): Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 rcNt=0x0
```

Someone that has experienced this problem before? Is my crypt32.dll corrupt?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just went through the same error when trying to start a VirtualBox VM. The VM started earlier in the day and after I installed some Windows updates it stopped working. Here is what fixed it:

1. Open Control Panel, Programs, View Installed Updates.
2. Scroll down to Microsoft Windows.
3. Find the Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3004394).
4. Select that update, then click Uninstall at the top.
5. Reboot and VirtualBox should again be working.

I just lost an hour to this problem.

Comment: I faced the same issue, but my machine (Win7 x64) did not have the mentioned patch installed, I uninstalled all the previously installed Windows patches (not the one for Office), and now my VM starts up again. Thank you very much for pushing into the right direction!

Comment: Thanks, after uninstalling that update and re-installing vm it works again

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same error today. Yesterday I've installed a few Windows updates. Commmands `vagrant halt`, `vagrant up`, `vagrant reload`  didn't help.

What I finally did was uninstalling Virtualbox and installing newest Virtualbox version + doing same for Vagrant (because I had Vagrant that didn't support newest Virtualbox - so in some cases it wouldn't be necessary).

After restarting PC, I could run `vagrant up` without a problem and everything is working as yesterday.