# Win7 Virtualbox is giving this error when trying to launch a vm: Error loading 'crypt32.dll': 1790

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I installed virtual box  4.3.28 in my windows 7 box, tried to open an imported VM and got the error below.

I've seen some posts from about 1/2 year ago stating this was a problem with some windows security fix, but I do not have that fix installed and I have installed the supposed cure for it, to no avail.

**KB3004394 is not on my system**

older fixes that aren't helping me ( I do not see the offending KB file installed on my machine)

[Vagrant laravel box, guest machine entered an invalid state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403840/vagrant-laravel-box-guest-machine-entered-an-invalid-state)

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13677

error I am seeing:

```
1618.161c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status -22900 (0xffffa68c)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll
1618.161c: Error (rc=0):
1618.161c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cached rc=Unknown Status -22900 (0xffffa68c) fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cHits=8 \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll
1618.161c: Error (rc=0):
1618.161c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\windows\system32\crypt32.dll' (C:\windows\system32\crypt32.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
1618.161c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0xc0000190 'C:\windows\system32\crypt32.dll'
1618.161c: Fatal error:
1618.161c: Error loading 'crypt32.dll': 1790 [C:\windows\system32\crypt32.dll]
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.  I upgraded from Virtualbox 4.2.something and bumped into this.  I uninstalled KB3004394, but is still broken. I'm using VMWare for the moment.

Comment: @JoelPearson no, I did not.  I went to vmware as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same error: `Error loading 'crypt32.dll'` on Win7 64bit, Vbox Version 5.1.10 r112026 (Qt5.6.2).

I've resolved in this way:

1. Start `cmd` as Admin
2. Run command: `sfc /scannow`

Answer (score 1):

From superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/851148/crypt32-dll-is-broken-for-virtualbox-since-patch-tuesday-9-dec-2014

Download patch from:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3024777

Important: make sure you download the x64 version for 64-bit systems.

Comment: This advice didn't help me. I have Windows 7 32bit and I don't have within kb 3004394 or kb 3024777 installed. The windows update service doesn't propose to me to install any of this. And I have the same error in virtualbox. If I try to install kb 3024777 manually, nothing happens, only trustedinstaller.exe runs and nothing at all.

Comment: @wazz have you tried restarting you PC? After installing kb 3024777? That installer literally doesn't show anything - no progress or that it completed.

Comment: I don't have 3004394. If I try to install 3024777 nothing happens. I tried to reboot the system. After reboot no 3024777 is installed. This update fix things after 3004394, but I don't have it, that's why I don't have any of this kb in my windows update list. But the problem with virtualbox exists.

Comment: The one thing that fix my problem - working with virtualbox version before  4.3.12.93733 without protection from modifying dll's by 3rd parties. Maybe the problem is with viruses or some app.

Answer (score 1):

download latest version of vm virtualbox. if you are using 4.3.xx, it has this bug.

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the ticket explaining the bug?

Comment: I don't have exact link but you can refer this one and many other if you google it. http://superuser.com/questions/838777/virtual-box-fail-load-virtual-machine-e-fail-0x80004005                                                                           https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=66364

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue with vb 4.16 and this fix solved it. 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45307