# Laravel Homestead on Windows - The guest machine entered an invalid state

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I can't run Vagrant/Homestead. I get the following error:

> The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
> to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
> 'unknown' state. Please verify everything is configured
> properly and try again.

[image: Vagrant]

Laravel homestead stuck on VM login:

[image: Login]

Any help?

Comment: Could you add your Homestead.yaml configuration file? also make sure you've added the Laravel homestead box (`vagrant box add Laravel/homestead`). BWT, there is a related topic in here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403840/vagrant-laravel-box-guest-machine-entered-an-invalid-state?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Open Virtual Box interface and then click on the ***show*** button.

Once Virtual Box opened, you need to login with user: vagrant and pass: vagrant.

Now It's working.